# UndefinedError in jinja condition

Tags: python, jinja2

```
{% if user.photo is defined %} 
{{ user.photo }}
{% else %}
#gravatar
{% endif %}
```

I am trying this code, but I am getting `UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined` in first line.

Everything works fine if i use this:

```
{% if user is defined %} 
{{ user.photo }}
{% else %}
#gravatar
{% endif %}
```

What is wrong with my first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` object isn't set, so test if *both* are present:

```
{% if user and user.photo %} 
    {{ user.photo }}
{% else %}
    #gravatar
{% endif %}
```

Just testing for boolean truthfulness should be enough.